# Change table/column/index names size in oracle 11g or 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

I use oracle 11g and need name that size is greater than 30 characters, I know the maximum size in 11g is 30 characters.

Can I change the this maximum size?

What is the maximum size of table/column/index names in Oracle 12c?

Comment: We all would love to use identifiers >30 chars, but why do you *need* them?

Comment: I wonder how you can cope without them. Having to compress the name of a table to fit 30 characters can lead to all sorts of issues with readability.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Database object names in [11g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) as well as in [12cR1](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223) are limited to 30 bytes (in a single-byte character set it will be equivalent to 30 characters).

Can it be changed? No, you cannot make any changes to allow Oracle to use object names that are greater than 30 bytes.

The 30 bytes object names restriction has been lifted in second release of [Oracle Database 12c ( 12cR2)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Database-Object-Names-and-Qualifiers.html#GUID-75337742-67FD-4EC0-985F-741C93D918DA) and if the value of the COMPATIBLE initialization parameter is set to 12.2 or higher then object names' length can be up to 128 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

I know of no way to change the maximum size of fields to more than 30 characters in 11g.

I've seen nothing to suggest this is changing in 12c.

Comment: It didn't.  Oracle is the worst database of all time.

Comment: @chubbsondubs Not Microsoft Access then?

Comment: Access may be bad, but at least it's user friendly.  Oracle is neither good nor usable.

Comment: I would argue that 'it's user friendly' will greatly depend on who the *user is*. Access is the most painful DB to use for me (software developer) but the best DB on the planet for my wife (insurance analyst).