# Oracle Identifier Maximum Length

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have a database in MS Sql server.
I want to migrate the same to Oracle also.

But there are few tables and column names that are 30 character long.
Oracle does not accept any identifier which is more than 30 characters long.

Is there any option in Oracle that allows us to increase the length of the identifier?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- The maximum identifier length is 30 characters.
- This is the latest discussion on stack overflow that shows there is no way to increase the identifier length
  [Change table/column/index names size in oracle 11g or 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248318/change-table-column-index-names-size-in-oracle-11g-or-12c)
- Also there is a discussion on oracle forum where users have a suggestion to change the length of identifier.
- https://community.oracle.com/ideas/3338