# When i run a specific query i get , ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1 ORA-12899: value too large for column"PLAN_TABLE"."OBJECT_NAME"

Tags: oracle12c, database-indexes

Am using *Oracle 12.1 c* when i run specific query ( i cant show for security reason , and because its un related); i get exception

```
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL 
level 1 ORA-12899: value too large for column "SOME_SCHEMA"."PLAN_TABLE"."OBJECT_NAME"  
(actual: 38, maximum: 30)
```

I cant make it work , i will try revert last changes i did because it was working before.

**BTW** i was doing Explain and doing index optimizations

Any idea why!
**P.S i will keep trying**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How i solved this:**

When i was reverting and reviewing my last changes i was doing alters for adding indexes, and each time i try to run the query again to make sure it is working.

So when i reached a specific alter i noticed the name of the index is too long,
so even if the index was created successfully, but the **explain plan for select**
was failing not the select it self.

**The solution:**

I renamed the index to be shorter ( 30 maximum ) it worked

[Change table/column/index names size in oracle 11g or 12c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248318/change-table-column-index-names-size-in-oracle-11g-or-12c/18248529)

[Why are Oracle table/column/index names limited to 30 characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378133/why-are-oracle-table-column-index-names-limited-to-30-characters)

[Using EXPLAIN PLAN Oracle websites docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231)

[image: check here summary]

Comment: It worked for me, thank u
The only thing that work.